# Regex (.NET) for look-behind with variable width - finding logical lines

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a text file where a logical line is made up of physical lines that are continued by having " !" at the end of the line. The following text (which doesn't have a trailing line-feed) would be 7 physical lines, but only 4 logical lines:

```
Single line logical line, followed by an empty line

Start of Logical line !
  indented End Of Logical Line
Start of Logical Line !
unindented logical line content !
End Of Logical Line (without trailing line-feed)
```

I've got this returning 5 matches (the last match is unwanted):

```
(?<logical_line>(?:[^\n]| +! *\n)*)(?<! !)(?:\n|\Z)
```

The sample text above allows for a " !" line-continuation marker, but I need to handle instances where white-space occurs before and after the " !" - For example: " +! *", but IIUC, using that in a look-behind isn't valid. That is, I need to be able to identify this as a single logical-line:

```
Some line with lots of spaces before and after the shriek     !     
end of line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a lookbehind, you only have to describe how looks the content you want to match:

```
(?m)(?<logical_line>^[^\n!]*(?: !\s*[^\n!]*)*$\n?)
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3Clogical_line%3E%5E%5B%5E%5Cn!%5D*%28%3F%3A%20!%5Cs*%5B%5E%5Cn!%5D*%29*%24%5Cn%3F%29&i=Some%20line%20with%20lots%20of%20spaces%20before%20and%20after%20the%20shriek%20%20%20%20%20!%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0Aend%20of%20line%0D%0A%0D%0ASingle%20line%20logical%20line%2C%20followed%20by%20an%20empty%20line%0D%0A%0D%0AStart%20of%20Logical%20line%20!%0D%0A%20%20indented%20End%20Of%20Logical%20Line%0D%0AStart%20of%20Logical%20Line%20!%0D%0Aunindented%20logical%20line%20content%20!%0D%0AEnd%20Of%20Logical%20Line%20%28without%20trailing%20line-feed%29&o=m)

Comment: nice, but that misses the empty line.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty complex regex there. The equivalent procedural code might not look pretty, but it's efficient enough and easy to read and understand.

```
var input = File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFile1.txt");
var str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    var line = input[i];
    while (line.EndsWith("!"))
    {
        i++;
        line += input[i];
    }
    str.AppendLine(line);
}
```